# SQL Join 3 Tables and concatenate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 Tables with a n:m Relation

Languages:

- ID (primary-key)
- name
- slug

Products:

- ID
- name
- slug
  -productgroup

Table for Relation:

Lang_Prod:

- lang_prod_id (composed from lang_id and prod_id)
- lang_id
- prod_id

Now i want to get all Products with their corresponding Language-Names:

- product
- productgroup
- language-names (multiple values)

I've tried:

```
SELECT product.*, languages_products.language_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(languages_products.language_id) as languages
FROM product
  INNER JOIN languages_products ON id = languages_products.product_id
GROUP BY product.id;
```

Result is:

- productname
- product_slug
- product_group
- String with languages IDs

Instead of the string with the language-IDs, i would like to have a string with language-names

How can i archieve that?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and should raise an error. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: it works fine, but is not what i need

Comment: "works fine but is not what I need" is a contradiction.

Comment: @jarlh No its not. Its not raising any errors (works fine), but is still not what i need (not what i need)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join with language table

```
SELECT product.id,product.name,product.productgroup,
       GROUP_CONCAT(l.name) as languages
FROM product
      INNER JOIN languages_products ON id = languages_products.product_id
      INNER JOIN languages l ON languages_products.language_id=l.id
    GROUP BY product.id,product.name,product.productgroup
```

Comment: Will raise an error in newer MySQL versions. (Unless in compability mode.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another join with the `languages` table, and use the `name` column from it. I'd group it in an inner query though:

```sql
SELECT p.*, languages
FROM  product p
JOIN  (SELECT   product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.name) as languages
       FROM     languages_products lp
       JOIN     languages l ON lp.language_id = l.id
       GROUP BY product_id) cl ON cl.product_id = p.id
```